# How to get list of products from last order and generate JSON object

Tags: php

I have the following code that is inserted in the head tag of the success.phtml

the json generated is like this:
as you can see order is is populated but the product list is not populated, I cant find out the reason

http://screencast.com/t/9aXNdGDOR

```
<?php

class ThePrinterDepo_Commissionjunction_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Get SKU, quantity, price and discount amount for each product in a given order
     * @param object $order
     * @return array
     */
    private function _getOrderProductsList($order)
    {
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        $purchasedSkus = array();
        $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) {
            $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
                'ITEM' => $orderItems[$i]['sku'],
                'QTY' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['qty_ordered'],0), // no decimals
                'AMT' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['price'],2), // 2 decimal places
                'DCNT' => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i]['discount_amount']),2)
            );
        }

        return $purchasedSkus;
    }

     /**
     * Get the Universal Data (JSON) Object for Commission Junction.
     * This object contains the order details passed on to Commission Junction for reporting purposes
     * on the Checkout Success / Order Confirmation page.
     * Notes:
     *  - CID, TYPE AND CURRENCY are hard coded
     * @param string $orderId
     * @return JSON object Universal Data Object for Commission Junction $json_masterTmsUdp
     */
    public function getCommissionJunctionUdo()
    {
        $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
            ->getLastRealOrderId();

        $orderId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->loadByIncrementId($lastOrderId)
            ->getEntityId();

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $udo = array();
        $udo['CID'] = 'XXXX';
        $udo['TYPE'] = 'XXXX';
        $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
        $udo['OID'] = $orderId;
        $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

        $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
        if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code))
        {
            $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
        }

        $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);

        if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('aff_commissionjunction') == 'cjafflx')
        {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
        }
        else
        {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
        }

        $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
        $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

        return $json_masterTmsUdo;

    }
}
?>
55
<script>var MasterTmsUdo = <?php $myObject = new ThePrinterDepo_Commissionjunction_Helper_Data(); echo $myObject->getCommissionJunctionUdo(); ?></script>
<script>/*DO NOT ALTER *** The Printer Depo*/(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});</script>
55
```

Comment: Is it the same question http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/42785?

Comment: What is the value of `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);` ?

Comment: its not printing out anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

Should be

```
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

**OR**

```
  $order =Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($lastOrderId);
```